# javascript countdown timer inside php loop not working

Tags: javascript, php, timer

*Hi I am trying to add multiple countdown timer through  javascript but some how, its not working , Can any one tell me what I am doing wrong, I am a new bee.*

below is by code:

```
php while loop {

    <script>
    var timer;

    var days= <?php echo $datediff ; ?>;     

    var compareDate = new Date();
    compareDate.setDate(compareDate.getDate() + <?php echo $datediff  ?> ); //just for this demo today + 7 days

    timer = setInterval(function() {
        timeBetweenDates(compareDate);
    }, 1000);

    function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
        var dateEntered = toDate;
        var now = new Date();
        var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

        if (difference <= 0) {
            // Timer done
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else {
            var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
            var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
            var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

            hours %= 24;
            minutes %= 60;
            seconds %= 60;

            $(".days") .text(days);
            $(".hours").text(hours);
            $(".minutes").text(minutes);
            $(".seconds").text(seconds);
       }    
    }
    </script>
    <div class="timer">
        <span class="days"></span>days
        <span class="hours"></span>hours
        <span class="minutes"></span>minutes
        <span class="seconds"></span>seconds
    </div>
```

I am not able to get the timer work have changed the id to class.

Comment: Hey, I tried and it worked for me. Did you check the console on the Developer Tools of your browser for any error? Show the full code here and I'll try to help you to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: Iam trying to work it inside a while loop here i fetch product info .

Comment: hold on let me put full code

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) { ?>

Answer (score 1):

If I got the idea correctly here you need to play with global and local variables here not to overwrite values of the global scope in every loop.

Check this code and let me know if it helps you out in some way.

```
<?php
$datediffs = [7, 8, 9, 10]; //let's say this is the array of results from the database
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var timer = []
    var timestamp = new Date()

    function timeBetweenDates(toDate, key) {
        var now = new Date()
        var difference = toDate.getTime() - now.getTime()

        if ( difference <= 0 )
        {
            // Timer done
            clearInterval( timer[key] );
        }
        else
        {
            var seconds = Math.floor( difference / 1000 )
            var minutes = Math.floor( seconds / 60 )
            var hours = Math.floor( minutes / 60 )
            var days = Math.floor( hours / 24 )

            hours %= 24
            minutes %= 60
            seconds %= 60

            var $timer = $( '.timer-' + key )

            $timer.find( '.days' ).text( days )
            $timer.find( '.hours' ).text( hours )
            $timer.find( '.minutes' ).text( minutes )
            $timer.find( '.seconds' ).text( seconds )
        }
    }
</script>

<?php foreach ( $datediffs as $key => $datediff ) : ?>
    <script>
        timer.push( setInterval( function()
        {
            var compareDate = new Date()
            compareDate.setTime( timestamp.getTime() )
            compareDate.setDate( compareDate.getDate() + <?php echo $datediff  ?> )
            timeBetweenDates( compareDate, <?php echo $key; ?> )
        }, 1000) )
    </script>

    <div class="timer-<?php echo $key; ?>">
        <span class="days"></span> days
        <span class="hours"></span> hours
        <span class="minutes"></span> minutes
        <span class="seconds"></span> seconds
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you replace for each loop with mysql while loop so it would be easy  for me to understand ?

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) { ?>    $datediff= $_row['days' ]       }

Comment: ok i have two dates stored in db  1. 2017-12-27 ( closing date )      2   2017-12-26( time stamp) now how do is start with

Comment: To change `foreach` for `while` just change the line
`<?php foreach ( $datediffs as $key => $datediff ) : ?>`
to
`<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) : $datediff= $_row['days' ] ?>`
and the line
`<?php endforeach; ?>`
by
`<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the idea with the two dates stored in the DB, rephrase your comment please.

Comment: two dates 'date posted'   &  'expire date'

Comment: I used your code , but how do I remove the empty timer bloc when the time is  finished .

Comment: How do i restart the timer after its over

Comment: can you help me to use this code with in php while loop